# Compare and print the value from array of array using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, nodes

Is there any way to check and compare value of array of array with the `name` only and print the matched value and unmatched value separately?

```
arrayToCheck =[
  {
    id: 1,
    name:Java,
    description: language
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name:JavaScript,
    description: language
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name:Oops,
    description: Subject
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name:Java,
    description: Practical
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name:Oops,
    description: Practical
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name:React Js,
    description: Practical
  },
]

valueToCheck= JavaScript;
```

Expected Output:

```
matchedValue = JavaScript

unMatchedValue = ['Java', 'Oops','React Js']; //filter repeated data
```

Comment: is it javascript?

Comment: yes @nur this is JavaScript

Comment: @Praveen Please make this a snippet

Comment: How ?? @KadenSkinner

Comment: You should go to edit and press the button that when you hover over it, it says snippet

Comment: in html put html, in JavaScript put JavaScript, in css put css

Comment: your edit que is full @Praveen I would allow most of them

Comment: like this ? @KadenSkinner

Comment: yes, now you need to put your code (not the snippet, that is good) in `~~~`

Comment: @Praveen ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: but i dont have code @KadenSkinner i need code to get this solution

Comment: I'm working on some code for you

Comment: Ok @KadenSkinner :)

Comment: @Praveen Did you mean to do a nested object instead of an array?

Comment: I found out the answer

Comment: where @KadenSkinner ?

Comment: I dont get you @Safder as i need to check value if it is present in aaray

Comment: even i dont know @KadenSkinner :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First-
Your array was made incorrectly.

It should have been like this.

```
var arrayToCheck =[
  {
    id: 1,
    name:"Java",
    description: "language",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name:"JavaScript",
    description: "language",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name:"Oops",
    description: "Subject",
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name:"Java",
    description: "Practical",
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name:"Oops",
    description: "Practical",
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name:"React Js",
    description: "Practical",
  },
]
```

You should also have a filter before all your code.
Like this-

```
var filter = {
name: "JavaScript"
};
```

Now you should have something like this.

```
var filter = {
name: "JavaScript"
};
var arrayToCheck =[
  {
    id: 1,
    name:"Java",
    description: "language",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name:"JavaScript",
    description: "language",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name:"Oops",
    description: "Subject",
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name:"Java",
    description: "Practical",
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name:"Oops",
    description: "Practical",
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name:"React Js",
    description: "Practical",
  },
]
```

Now to use the filter and log it in the console.

```js
var filter = {
name: "JavaScript"
};
var arrayToCheck =[
  {
    id: 1,
    name:"Java",
    description: "language",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name:"JavaScript",
    description: "language",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name:"Oops",
    description: "Subject",
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name:"Java",
    description: "Practical",
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name:"Oops",
    description: "Practical",
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name:"React Js",
    description: "Practical",
  },
]
arrayToCheck= arrayToCheck.filter(function(item) {
  for (var key in filter) {
    if (item[key] === undefined || item[key] != filter[key])
      return false;
  }
  return true;
});

console.log(arrayToCheck)
```

Comment: Hi a small query if i need rest of the values which does not match to filter then how to print them ?

Comment: I will find out

Comment: @Kaden Skinner. use an array. `var ids = [2]` then filter id from `ids` like: `arrayToCheck.filter(({id}) => ids.includes(id))`

Comment: I know. Praveen Just wanted one filter though.

Comment: @Praveen No problem  Still looking for ways to solve the second part of your question

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. and please don't make any chat room again.

Comment: @Praveen I have so far no answer to getting the other values. I will come back to this question once I find a answer. By the way, why do you need to show the other values?

Comment: so i can add them to my database which does not match with filter :)

Comment: @Praveen Ok. 1 more thing. Do you want the other values to print regardless or only if there isn't a item in the array that matches your filter?

Comment: only by name i want to add